# IntelliJ no "watches" tab in debugging

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

Normally I use the "watches" feature in the IntelliJ IDEA to for debugging. 
But now the watches-tab seems to be  gone.

**It should look like this:**

[image]

**For the watches are missing:**

[image]

Any hints how to get them back?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay it was a bit hard to find but clicking on the small three dots on the top right corner bings the watches in the variables tab bag.

**The view changed.** Everything is in one tab now not separate.

[image]